# Conway's game of life in Python 3 with matplotlib - problem with displaying a formation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, conways-game-of-life

I am currently trying to program a python 3 implementation of the game of life. My main goal was to display a grid of the size n that gets filled randomly according to conway's rules.
That part works fine.

Now I wanted to implement a second mode that allows you to start with one of the given formations - in my first try a glider.

Here is the main():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from gol_functions import *

def main():

    # get arguments from input function
    arguments = input_arguments()
    # set the arguments 
    gridsize = int(arguments.gridsize)
    interval = int(arguments.interval)
    formation = arguments.formationflag

    # if you want to start with a formation:
    if formation:
        grid = np.zeros(gridsize*gridsize).reshape(gridsize, gridsize)
        add_glider(1, 1, grid)

    # else display a randopm grid
    else:
        grid = randomgrid(gridsize)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # colormap: black -> alive, white -> dead
    img = ax.imshow(grid, cmap='binary', interpolation='nearest')

    # this will be used to save the animation in a later version
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=(img, grid, gridsize,),
                                  frames=10,
                                  interval=interval,
                                  save_count=50)

    # remove x and y - axis labels, numbers and ticks
    ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    # plot the animated output
    plt.show()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Here is the function for adding the glider:

```
def add_glider(i, j, grid):
    """adds a glider with top-left cell at (i, j)"""
    glider = np.array([[0,    0, 255],
                       [255,  0, 255],
                       [0,  255, 255]])

    grid[i:i+3, j:j+3] = glider
```

It adds a glider in the grid @ position 1, 1

And here is my update function:

```
def update(frameNum, img, grid, gridsize):
    """Updates the grid every time it is refreshed"""
    newgrid = grid.copy()
    for i in range(gridsize):
        for j in range(gridsize):
            # this formula considers the edge/boundary conditions that appear
            # every cell has to have 8 neighbouring cells
            # to implement this in a grid of size n we simply fold the 4 edges to each parallel edge
            # we'll end up with a cylinder first, then with a geometric shape called torus (google it.)
            total = int((grid[i, (j - 1) % gridsize] + grid[i, (j + 1) % gridsize] +
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, j] + grid[(i + 1) % gridsize, j] +
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, (j - 1) % gridsize] +             
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, (j + 1) % gridsize] +
                         grid[(i + 1) % gridsize, (j - 1) % gridsize] + grid[
                         (i + 1) % gridsize, (j + 1) % gridsize]) / 255)

        # apply conway's basic rules of the game of life for each cell
            if grid[i, j] == ON:
                if (total < 2) or (total > 3):
                    newgrid[i, j] = OFF
            else:
                if total == 3:
                    newgrid[i, j] = ON
                    # update data
                    img.set_data(newgrid)
                    grid[:] = newgrid[:]
                    return img,
```

However when I run it with the option to have it display the glider, all I see is the following formation...

[failedglider_1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mql6F.jpg)

which swiftly turns into this and becomes static:

[failedglider_2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4aWw.png)

... instead of an actual glider as seen in the matrix of add_glider. So it seems that somehow the program adds an unwanted alive cell right at the top. I tried to find where it comes from... but I can't find it.

Does anyone have any clues? I am greatful for all help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some minor fixes to the code from your original post I am able to produce exactly what you wanted. The modified code is listed at the bottom. First frame is shown on the left in the image bellow. After few frames it looks like the image on the right.
So the glider seems to work just fine :)

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# call with: python3 cgl.py 10 500 1 1

import os
import argparse
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

ON = 255
OFF = 0


def update(frameNum, img, grid, gridsize):
    """Updates the grid every time it is refreshed"""
    newgrid = grid.copy()
    for i in range(gridsize):
        for j in range(gridsize):
            # this formula considers the edge/boundary conditions that appear
            # every cell has to have 8 neighbouring cells
            # to implement this in a grid of size n we simply fold the 4 edges to each parallel edge
            # we'll end up with a cylinder first, then with a geometric shape called torus (google it.)
            total = int((grid[i, (j - 1) % gridsize] + grid[i, (j + 1) % gridsize] +
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, j] + grid[(i + 1) % gridsize, j] +
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, (j - 1) % gridsize] +
                         grid[(i - 1) % gridsize, (j + 1) % gridsize] +
                         grid[(i + 1) % gridsize, (j - 1) % gridsize] + grid[
                         (i + 1) % gridsize, (j + 1) % gridsize]) / 255)

        # apply conway's basic rules of the game of life for each cell
            if grid[i, j] == ON:
                if (total < 2) or (total > 3):
                    newgrid[i, j] = OFF
            else:
                if total == 3:
                    newgrid[i, j] = ON
    # update data
    grid[:] = newgrid[:]
    img.set_data(newgrid)
    return img,


def add_glider(i, j, grid):
    """adds a glider with top-left cell at (i, j)"""
    glider = np.array([[0,    0, 255],
                       [255,  0, 255],
                       [0,  255, 255]])

    grid[i:i+3, j:j+3] = glider


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Conway's game of life in Python 3")
    parser.add_argument('gridsize', type=int, help='Dimension of grid.')
    parser.add_argument('interval', type=int, help='Interval.')
    parser.add_argument('formationflag', type=bool, help='Predefined formation.')
    parser.add_argument('frame', type=int, help='How many frames to animate.')

    # get arguments from input function
    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    # set the arguments
    frame = int(arguments.frame)
    gridsize = int(arguments.gridsize)
    interval = int(arguments.interval)
    formation = arguments.formationflag

    # if you want to start with a formation:
    if formation:
        grid = np.zeros(gridsize*gridsize).reshape(gridsize, gridsize)
        add_glider(1, 1, grid)

    # else display a randopm grid
    else:
        grid = randomgrid(gridsize)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # colormap: black -> alive, white -> dead
    img = ax.imshow(grid, cmap='binary', interpolation='nearest')

    # # this will be used to save the animation in a later version
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=(img, grid, gridsize,),
                                  frames=frame,
                                  interval=interval,
                                  save_count=50)

    # remove x and y - axis labels, numbers and ticks
    ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    # plot the animated output
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("DONE")
```

Comment: funcAnimation is a function of the matplotlib library animation.
Sorry, forgot to include the imports in my post - corrected that.

Thanks for looking into it though - now I know that the problem seems to be with the funcAnimation parameters.

Comment: Oh cool, I have updated the gist code. Now it works and animates the glider nicely. If this solves the problem consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your effort! I don't quite understand, why it works if you use argument parsing but not if you get the input via a regular "variable = input(xy)" prompt in the command line...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Good point. The code is now listed in the answer. Thanks.
@AndyM. Well not sure why and if that is the case. Only reason why I used argument parsing is because I am familiar with it. I have no idea what your `input_arguments` does so I couldn't use it. If you return the argument values in correct data type, there should be no problems. I hope it answers your question now.

Comment: Thanks! I found the error, There was a problem with my input function. It works now,
I marked your question as the solution. Thanks a lot for your help!